# scalate does not compile templates in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, scala, scalate

I am trying to make scalate work under tomcat, but it crashes when it tries to compile the scaml templates. No problem with Jetty. I am new to this and tomcat in general. It seems also the scalatra-sbt prototype on github crashes, which makes me think it's tomcat not configured correctly.

```
org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateException: scala/tools/nsc/settings/ScalaSettings
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoad(TemplateEngine.scala:738)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoadEntry(TemplateEngine.scala:595)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.liftedTree1$1(TemplateEngine.scala:327)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:321)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:391)
    org.scalatra.scalate.ScalateSupport$class.renderErrorPage(ScalateSupport.scala:50)
    com.example.MyScalatraFilter.renderErrorPage(MyScalatraFilter.scala:7)
    org.scalatra.scalate.ScalateSupport$class.handleError(ScalateSupport.scala:46)
    com.example.MyScalatraFilter.handleError(MyScalatraFilter.scala:7)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraKernel.scala:109)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:71)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:71)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraKernel.scala:99)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:99)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:99)
    scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:71)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$class.handle(ScalatraKernel.scala:98)
    com.example.MyScalatraFilter.handle(MyScalatraFilter.scala:7)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraFilter.scala:18)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply(ScalatraFilter.scala:18)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply(ScalatraFilter.scala:18)
    scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:71)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$class.doFilter(ScalatraFilter.scala:17)
    com.example.MyScalatraFilter.doFilter(MyScalatraFilter.scala:7)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/tools/nsc/settings/ScalaSettings
    org.fusesource.scalate.support.ScalaCompiler$.create(ScalaCompiler.scala:170)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compiler(TemplateEngine.scala:154)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoad(TemplateEngine.scala:655)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoadEntry(TemplateEngine.scala:595)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.liftedTree1$1(TemplateEngine.scala:327)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:321)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:391)
    org.scalatra.scalate.ScalateSupport$class.renderErrorPage(ScalateSupport.scala:50)
    com.example.MyScalatraFilter.renderErrorPage(MyScalatraFilter.scala:7)
    org.scalatra.scalate.ScalateSupport$class.handleError(ScalateSupport.scala:46)
    com.example.MyScalatraFilter.handleError(MyScalatraFilter.scala:7)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraKernel.scala:109)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:71)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:71)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraKernel.scala:99)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:99)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:99)
    scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:71)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$class.handle(ScalatraKernel.scala:98)
    com.example.MyScalatraFilter.handle(MyScalatraFilter.scala:7)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraFilter.scala:18)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply(ScalatraFilter.scala:18)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply(ScalatraFilter.scala:18)
    scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:71)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$class.doFilter(ScalatraFilter.scala:17)
    com.example.MyScalatraFilter.doFilter(MyScalatraFilter.scala:7)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.tools.nsc.settings.ScalaSettings
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
    org.fusesource.scalate.support.ScalaCompiler$.create(ScalaCompiler.scala:170)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compiler(TemplateEngine.scala:154)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoad(TemplateEngine.scala:655)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoadEntry(TemplateEngine.scala:595)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.liftedTree1$1(TemplateEngine.scala:327)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:321)
    org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:391)
    org.scalatra.scalate.ScalateSupport$class.renderErrorPage(ScalateSupport.scala:50)
    com.example.MyScalatraFilter.renderErrorPage(MyScalatraFilter.scala:7)
    org.scalatra.scalate.ScalateSupport$class.handleError(ScalateSupport.scala:46)
    com.example.MyScalatraFilter.handleError(MyScalatraFilter.scala:7)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraKernel.scala:109)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:71)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:100)
    scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:71)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraKernel.scala:99)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:99)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(ScalatraKernel.scala:99)
    scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:71)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraKernel$class.handle(ScalatraKernel.scala:98)
    com.example.MyScalatraFilter.handle(MyScalatraFilter.scala:7)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraFilter.scala:18)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply(ScalatraFilter.scala:18)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply(ScalatraFilter.scala:18)
    scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:71)
    org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter$class.doFilter(ScalatraFilter.scala:17)
    com.example.MyScalatraFilter.doFilter(MyScalatraFilter.scala:7)
```

Any hint on how to make scalate compiler work under tomcat?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to setup scalate in a tomcat server, but I can't find any resource explaining how to do that. What jars to download and from where? Where to add those jars? any modifications to the web.xml file?
Can you help me with any of those questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have `scala-compiler.jar` deployed with the other jars?

Comment: no, and by packaging and deploying it it solved my problem. Thanks a lot for your help!